# infinite scroll - how to delay the ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a pretty simple script that works fine. However, i want to delay the appending of new results for 3 seconds, to avoid over-loading the server. So, when you reach the end of the page, a loading image should be displayed for 3 seconds, and **only after that**, the ajax request should be made.

How do i make the "delay"?

Here is the script:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
         var lastID = $('div.row-details').last().attr("id");

         $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();

         $.ajax({url: "/projects.php?lastID=" + lastID,
            success: function(html){
                if(html){
                       $("#maintable").append(html);
                       $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                 }else{
                       $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                   }
              }
           });
      } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the AJAX call in an anonymous function passed to `setTimeout()`, something like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/projects.php?lastID=" + lastID,
        success: function(html) {
            if (html) {
                $("#maintable").append(html);
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
            } else {
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
            }
        }
    });
}, 3000);
```

Comment: i have tried that,  it works just for the first time i hit the end of the page. and then, everything becomes a mess :(

Comment: @develroot Can you be more specific than "becomes a mess"? What precisely is the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: Can you post the code that you have using `setTimeout()` in the question?

Comment: Consider the case where the user hits the end of the page, sees the loading animation, scrolls up and then scrolls down immediately. This second scroll down will happen within 3 seconds, causing the ajax fetch function to be called twice with the same lastId. What you want is to keep track of all lastIds requested. If you see a lastId that has been requested, you dont request it again. If the ajax returned error, you remove lastId from the array its being stored in. This way, the user can try scrolling down again and request the next page one more time.

Answer (score 0):

for your remark: "i have tried that, it works just for the first time i hit the end of the page. and then, everything becomes a mess :( ",

can you try clearTimeout();? if you scroll condition is met again within 3 seconds, ajax call will not be made. probably solves your mess up issue.

```
var timeoutId;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
             var lastID = $('div.row-details').last().attr("id");
             clearTimeout(timeoutId);   // no problem if invalid id, there is no exception     
             $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
               timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/projects.php?lastID=" + lastID,
                        success: function(html) {
                            if (html) {
                                $("#maintable").append(html);
                                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                            } else {
                                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }, 3000);

          } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are solutions that don't require you to wait 3 seconds before the *first* AJAX call. Check out [Underscore's `throttle()`](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) function.